# Give condition for @html.checkboxFor()

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a boolean value in my `model.obj.notify`. I need to check the checkbox if the value is true. Is there a way to condition in the code

```
<label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.NotifyEdit,new { id="chkNotifyEdit"})  Notify Me
</label>
```

Comment: The checkbox will automatically be checked when `m.NotifyEdit` is true.

Comment: Oh! My mistake! I had not bound the value to "notify". So the value was always set as false. Now get it !@Marthijn